# how to create rounded edittexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I am new to android, currently. I have created simple EditTexts and search bar type EditText .. But now I am stuck at creating attached EditTexts like in the following snapshot.
[image]

Comment: You could use parent LinearLayout view and make it roundtable using shapes (like answer below). Then just put any number of EditText views and using separator view between them.

Comment: @Sharj can you put your text in answer, i would accept it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use parent LinearLayout view and make it roundtable using shapes (like the other answer). Then just put any number of EditText views and use separator view between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
   <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

using the following xml code to create a new drawable and set it as background to your LinearLayout that contains EditViews.

Answer (score 2):

for 1st edit text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dp" 
             android:topRightRadius="4dp"  />

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#777" />

</shape>
```

second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >



    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#777" />

</shape>
```

third:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
             android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#777" />

</shape>
```